# How do I receive the APNS token for iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I've been trying to setup push notifications on iOS 13.4 for a week now and I've been getting nowhere. I setup a blank application with just the minimal amount of code and it still doesn't seem to work. I get the log that the user has granted permissions but I do not receive the APNS token, I do not receive an error and method doesn't even get called. What might I be doing wrong?

I have setup the app id to have push notifications on the certificates and profiles page. I have also setup capabilities to have push notifications, remote notifications and background fetch.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

      UNAuthorizationOptions authOptions = UNAuthorizationOptionAlert |
          UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge;

      [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter]
          requestAuthorizationWithOptions:authOptions
          completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if(granted){
          NSLog(@"PERMISSION GRANTED");
        }
        else{
          NSLog(@"PERMISSION GRANTED");
        }
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
        });
      }];

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken {
  NSLog(@"DEVICE DID REGISTER:");
  NSLog(@"DEVICE TOKEN: %s", deviceToken);
}


- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError*)error {
    NSLog(@"DEVICE DID FAIL TO REGISTER:");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check in apple developer account the certificates you have created having your device UDID or not. Also take care of that if you are testing it on simulator than it will not work. You can only check notifications on real devices.

Secondly APNS works when your app is in background mode to fetch notifications in foreground mode we need to make some settings in the app or else need to use third party libraries.

If need to check the complete scenario you can check the link attached below:-
https://www.appcoda.com/push-notification-ios/